# Changing android:label - Android Studio

Tags: android

I'd like to change the android:label.

When clicking on the title between the quotations, it automatically changes to

`@string/app_name`.

Note: I'd like to change the label itself; not by using

`setTitle("Title")`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Then replace `@string/app_name` with the string you want...

Comment: ^ Nope, that doesn't work. This worked for me... http://stackoverflow.com/a/36634303/6206074.
Thanks for your effort though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to strings.xml file and change the value.

Or

Press Ctrl+Click on app_name it will take you to strings.xml and change the text "Title" to whatever you need.